# Drools : stop a rule from firing after a number of executions

Tags: drools

I'm trying to figured out how to stop a rule from firing after a number of executions.
Let's say you grant a discount if you buy an item X (current price $10), but this discount can be granted only 2 times per customer.

so my rule is as follow:

```
 rule "Fixed Price Promotion Item X"

 when
     $o : Order( )
     $ol1 : OrderLine( item.code == "X" )
 then
    FixedPrice fixedPrice = new FixedPrice(8.80, $ol1.getItem().getPrice().doubleValue(), $ol1.getItem().getBarcode(), 1, "e78fbca5ed014f49806ad667aea80965" , "Happy Mother's day!! This is a fixed price promotion" );
    insertLogical (fixedPrice); //here I grant a promotion
```

Originally, I thought to have another rule to insert a fact when my condition was met so It would stop my promotion rule from firing.

I would have something like this:

```
declare LimitReachedOut
   promotionId : String
end

rule "stop Promotion"
when
     Number($numOfGrantedProm : intValue) from accumulate ( 
                                FixedPrice(promotionId == "123",
                                        $count: quantity),
                                sum($count)
            )
then
    if( $numOfGrantedProm == 2  ){ //this cause an issue, even > 1 or >=2 will keep inserting new LimitReachedOut("123") recursively.
        insertLogical (new LimitReachedOut("123"));
     }
end  


rule "Fixed Price Promotion Item X"
 when
     not( LimitReachedOut( promotionId == "123" ) )
     $o : Order( )
     $ol1 : OrderLine( item.code == "X" ) 
 then
    FixedPrice fixedPrice = new FixedPrice(8.80, $ol1.getItem().getPrice().doubleValue(), $ol1.getItem().getBarcode(), 1, "123" , "Happy Mother's day!! This is a fixed price promotion" );
    insertLogical (fixedPrice);

 end
```

Is there another way to do it?

I will really appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to accomplish what I wanted, and I'm posting it in here just if someone wants to use this as well.
I'm basically not executing the RHS of the rule putting a conditional clause there.

Firstly, I'm calculating the number of Facts that were inserted into the working memory ( FixedPrice with an id called ruleId to link the facts to this particular rule ) using the **accumulate function**. 
Secondly, the condition in the RHS if( $numOfGrantedProm < 2  ) means that I will execute the block inside of the conditional if (create & insert fixedPrice fact) up to two times.
The rule will be fired anyway but the **if** condition will avoid executing the block of code.

```
rule "Fixed Price Promotion Item X"

when
   $o : Order( )
   $ol1 : OrderLine( item.code == "X" )
   Number($numOfGrantedProm : intValue) from accumulate ( 
                                           FixedPrice(ruleId == 
                           "e78fbca5ed014f49806ad667aea80965",$count:quantity),
                           sum($count)
                      )
then
   if( $numOfGrantedProm < 2  ){ 
       FixedPrice fixedPrice = new FixedPrice(8.80,
                                   $ol1.getItem().getPrice().doubleValue(),
                                   $ol1.getItem().getBarcode(), 
                                   1, 
                                   "e78fbca5ed014f49806ad667aea80965" , 
                                   "Happy Mother's day!! This is a fixed price 
                                    promotion" );
       insertLogical (fixedPrice); //here I grant a promotion enter code here
    }
end
```